# Swapping the 2 children node pointers of a root in tree data structure

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

I have created a binary tree with 5 as root, then I created its left node as 6 and right node as 7.Further, I performed swapping between the two pointers (the left child pointer and right child pointer) and I expected the two children nodes of the root to be swapped (Since root's left child is lefft and later I equated it to rightt). Is there any conceptual error in my thinking?What am I missing here about pointers?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
struct node* newNode(int value){
    struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    temp->data=value;
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
   // ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
    struct node* root=newNode(5);
    struct node* leftt=newNode(6);
    struct node* rightt=newNode(7);
    root->left=leftt;
    root->right=rightt;
    cout<<root->data<<" "<<root->left->data<<" "<<root->right->data<<" ";//prints 5 6 7 (expected)
    cout<<'\n';
    struct node* temp;
    temp=leftt;
    leftt=rightt;
    rightt=temp;
    cout<<root->data<<" "<<root->left->data<<" "<<root->right->data<<'\n';//prints 5 6 7. Shouldn't it print 5 7 6?
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not swap the pointers from root which you output.

Comment: temp=leftt, etc, is not swapping the pointers. You want tmp=root->left, etc.

Comment: Given the code you have, the most straightforward way to swap is: `root->left = rightt; root->right = leftt;`, but that is not very instructive...

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is clearly not C, but bad style C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not swap the pointers from root which you output.
The way you swap it affects the separate variables, but nothing inside your tree.
I.e. you swap the variables from which you initialise the pointers inside the tree.

Changing the swapping part like this should help.

```
temp=root->left;
root->left=root->right;
root->right=temp;
```

You could also move the copying (from the separate variables into the pointers inside the tree) to after the swapping of those variables, but that is probably not the point, the goal of your question.

Referring to your comment (indicating that you want the swapping code to have the swapping effect without changing it):
You seem to be thinking of pointers to pointers. If the left and right from a node point to pointers (which point to nodes), then changing those pointers to nodes would result in the desired effect.
But that seems unusual and would require dynamically allocating the pointers in addition to the nodes with pointers to pointers...

Comment: Yes, this(what you mentioned) would do the work, but I am unable to figure out what is wrong with that code? I mean I set root->left equal to a pointer and later when the pointer is pointing to something else, shouldn't the root->left should also change without mentioning it as root->left? Because then, I don't need the root to change its left child or right child.

Comment: If you find some conceptual error in my thinking, please let me know.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of pointers to pointers. If the left and rigth from a node point to pointers which point to nodes, then changing those pointers would result in the desired effect. But that is very unusual and would require dynamically allocating the pointers in addition to the nodes with pointers to pointers...

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same and I found out where I was going wrong.

Comment: Now that you have included the comment part in the answer, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is that you have swapped the values of the local variables `leftt` and `rightt`. This swap does not affect the member variables of the `root` node.

If you create a helper function to set the left and right children of a node:

```
void set_children(node* root, node* leftt, node* rightt)
{
    root->left = leftt;
    root->right = rightt;
}
```

Then in `main`, you can set root with:

```
set_children(root, leftt, rightt);
```

And then the swap can be done like this:

```
set_children(root, root->right, root->left);
```

A helper function can also be written to do this swap.

```
void swap_children(node* n)
{
    set_children(n, n->right, n->left);
}
```

So then, in `main`, you would do:

```
swap_children(root);
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use root every time I wish to swap the nodes. Can it be done without that?

Comment: `root` is just the name of the function parameter. You can pass in any node to the function.